# return key-value pair key based on key-value pair value date with sorting

Tags: python-3.x

I have the follow list:

```
test = [{'date': '2021-07-01 20:32:48', 'name': 'foo'}, {'date': '2022-02-17 10:07:25', 'name': 'bar'}, {'date': '2022-02-18 04:00:05', 'name': 'baz'}]
```

I want to return the name attached to the most recent date. `baz` in this example. I probably need to use this but I don't know how: `.sort(key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x['date'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))`

I tried something like this:

```
sorted_list = test.sort(key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x['date'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
print(sorted_list[0])
```

I read that `list methods work in-place` so i'm wondering how I can use it in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this

```
test = [{'date': '2021-07-01 20:32:48', 'name': 'foo'}, {'date': '2021-02-19 10:07:25', 'name': 'bar'}, {'date': '2022-02-18 04:00:05', 'name': 'baz'}]
sortedList = sorted(test, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x['date'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), reverse=True)
print(sortedList[0]['name'])

> baz
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```py
from datetime import datetime

test = [{'date': '2021-07-01 20:32:48', 'name': 'foo'},
        {'date': '2022-02-17 10:07:25', 'name': 'bar'},
        {'date': '2022-02-18 04:00:05', 'name': 'baz'}]

sorted_list = sorted(test, key=lambda d: datetime.strptime(d['date'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), reverse=True)
print(sorted_list[0])
```

Output:

```
{'date': '2022-02-18 04:00:05', 'name': 'baz'}
```